# What are the distinctions between lexical and static scoping?

Tags: language-agnostic, scope, lexical-scope

In [R programing for those coming from other languages](http://www.johndcook.com/R_language_for_programmers.html) John Cook says that

> R uses lexical scoping while S-PLUS uses static scope. The difference can be subtle, particularly when using closures.

I found this odd because I have always thought lexical scoping and static scoping where synonymous.

Are there distinct attributes to lexical and static scoping, or is this a distinction that changes from community to community, person to person?  If so, what are the general camps and how do I tell them apart so I can better understand someones meaning when they use these words.

Comment: I'm guessing they meant `dynamic` instead of `lexical`.

Comment: @Mehrdad R is not dynamically scoped

Comment: Weiird.. curious to see what they meant then. Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_%28computer_science%29) (and I) agree with you that the terms "lexical scope" and "static scope" are synonymous.  [This Lua discussion](http://lua-users.org/wiki/LuaScopingDiscussion) tries to make a distinction, but notes that people don't agree as to what that distinction is. :-)

It appears to me that the attempted distinction has to do with accessing names in a different function-activation-record ("stack block", if you will) than the most-current-execution record, which mainly (only?) occurs in nested functions:

```
function f:
    var x
    function h:
        var y
        use(y)  -- obviously, accesses y in current activation of h
        use(x)  -- the question is, which x does this access?
```

With lexical scope, the answer is "the activation of `f` that called the activation of `h`" and with dynamic scope it means "the most recent activation that has any variable named `x`" (which might not be `f`).  On the other hand, if the language forbids the use of `x` at all, there's no question about "which `x` is this" since the answer is "error". :-)  It looks as though some people use "static scope" to refer to this third case.

Comment: So in other words, lexical scoping without closure?

Comment: Yes.  Of course I (like the OP) am actually guessing what they mean.

Comment: This discussion of S-PLUS vs R scoping apears to back up your claim.  Lua's `%` name-prefixing seems like a lot more fun then this `assign` business.  https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2005-June/073091.html

Answer (score 4):

R official documentation also addresses differences of scope between R and S-plus:
http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html#Scope

The example given from the link can be simplified like this:

```
 cube <- function(n) {
   sq <- function() n*n
   n*sq()
 }
```

The results from S-Plus and R are different:

```
 ## first evaluation in S
 S> cube(2)
 Error in sq(): Object "n" not found
 Dumped
 S> n <- 3
 S> cube(2)
 [1] 18
 ## then the same function evaluated in R
 R> cube(2)
 [1] 8
```

I personally think the way of treating variable in R is more natural.